# Canon 5D MKIII - how to view the photos of the full card?

Tags: canon-5d-mark-iii

I have an SD and a CF card in my camera. Once the CF card is full, it switches to the SD card. But when I try to view the photos taken, it shows only those on the SD card once the CF is full. How can I see the CF card photos without taking out the SD card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 118 of your [Canon 5D MkIII manual](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/E1e-92xRLBS.pdf) covers this:

> If [**Record func.**] is set to [**Standard**] or [**Auto switch card**], select the card for recording and playing images.
>
> If [**Record func.**] is set to [**Rec. separately**] or [**Rec. to multiple**], select the card for playing images.

[image]